# Run php command inside bash script inside Docker container with ubuntu image

Tags: php, bash, docker

I have a bash script and a php script.

--------EDIT--------
I SOLVED IT, I AM JUST STUPID, I WROTE MY ANSWER BELOW.

(I can put code screenshots if you want.)

MY DOCKERFILE:

```
ARG VERSION=latest
FROM ubuntu:bionic
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
COPY ./resources/ start.sh /sandbox/
WORKDIR /sandbox/
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","start.sh"]
```

I want to execute them in a docker container as i said in the title.

The 'entry point' of the docker container is the bash script.

Inside the bash script i have a line

```
php PHP_SCRIPT.php
```

But when i execute, it gives me the error:

PHP_SCRIPT.php: php: not found

or something like that

i saw that the php command usually resides in '/usr/bin/php',
but i tried to run the command 'which php' in the docker container and the result was '/usr/local/bin/php'

Maybe i am calling the php command wrong?

But the result that i want is to run a php script INSIDE a bash script that starts when i start the docker container.

Comment: Have you tried with the full path of the PHP_SCRIPT.php file?

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile?

Comment: @jordanm i edited the question now to show it.

Comment: If you want to use PHP you should use the php base image or install php inside of the one you are using.

Comment: @NigelRen i tried with just PHP_SCRIPT.php and with /sandbox/PHP_SCRIPT.php and still i would get the same error. but the error says that it does not find php, not that it does not find the file

Comment: @jordanm and how do i install it in the image. I tried changing the line to "RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y install php:cli". and when i would start the container, its like it froze, or take very long to do something. It would not show or do anything for quite a while. Maybe the "php:cli" part i wrote wrong?

Comment: php:cli doesn't look like a valid package name to me, but in that case it should have failed to build.

Comment: ok. i added another line "RUN apt-get php-cli" and o got an error "returned a non zero code 100". im searching about it now. but also tried changing the line i wrote above to have - instead of :, but it would not return any error, it would just freeze. If you know something about the error please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the docker image `FROM ubuntu:bionic` which does not have PHP installed by default. Try `FROM php` (or one of the [many tags available](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=tags)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that PHP is not installed in your container
To do this, you can use your official PHP image
https://hub.docker.com/_/php

```
FROM php:7.4-cli

ARG VERSION=latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
COPY ./resources/ start.sh /sandbox/
WORKDIR /sandbox/
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","start.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

And i would get the "php not found error" because i didnt install php to the docker container.

So, I tried writing in the dockerfile

RUN apt-get php-cli (i also tried with php:cli and seemed to have same effect),

to try to install php to container, but when i would start container it would seem like it would freeze and not do anything.

Apparenty, it doesnt 'freeze', but i only had to wait for the php to update in the container. :D

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).